# How to open new window on production build NW-React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nw.js

I need to open a new window to preview the document before print it.

I using the Router to separate requests by its paths:

```html
    <Router>
        <Suspense fallback={''}>
            <Switch>
                <Print path="/print/:thingId" />
                < . . . >
                <App default />
            </Switch>
        </Suspense>
    </Router>
```

I try to open a new window through `nw.Window.open()` and `<Link />` component from `react-router-dom` module.

When i use *next code* on DEVELOPMENT build thats works as was expected: window are opens and loads the content.

```js
nw.Window.open(nw.Window.get().window.location.origin + '/print/123');
```

```html
<Link to={'/print/123'} target="_blank">Print this!!</Link>
```

But on PRODUCTION build this shows **404 Not Found** page.

**How i can open a new window on PRODUCTION build??**

Comment: console.log that and determine what values you are getting in production and change accordingly

Comment: @Justcode DEVELOPMENT build runs on `http://localhost:3000/` but PRODUCTION build works on `chrome-extension://` scheme and host specified in `package.json`. Any thoughts??